# TypeError: Cannot read property 'manager' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity

I'am testing an ethereum smart contract using remix.
Am using injected web3. 
The deployment of the smart contract succeed. then i use the ABI & the adress of the deployed smart contract to develop simple front end using react, but this error appears TypeError: Cannot read property 'manager' of null .

smart contract

```
"pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract dapp {
    address public manager;

    function dapp() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }
}"
```

App.js

```
"import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import web3 from './web3';
import dapp from './dapp';

class App extends Component {
  async compenentDidMount(){
    const manager = await dapp.methods.manager().call();
    this.setState({ manager });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> The manager is {this.state.manager} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;"
```

web3.js

```
"import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

export default web3;"
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `state` object in `constructor()`:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      manager: ""
    }
  }
  async compenentDidMount(){
  ...
  ...
}
```